# Yii Login Issue In Facebook Share Content

Tags: php, facebook, yii

I am stuck in a problem.

I have a Yii shopping cart only for registered users. I have added a facebook share button in it.
But when I am sharing any product, I am not able to get the product image or any details.
Instead I am getting the details from the login page.

I have checked the link in the facebook debug tool([https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)).
It show

- Fetched URL as original URL(URL for sharing and for fetching the
  contents)
- Canonical URL as /user/login

Seems like the product page is checked but was redirected to the login page from where the details like 
og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image etc are called from the login page.

Is there any method to keep the authentication and allow the facebook to share the details? 
I think the problem can be solved within the Yii coding itself.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: it is better to keep the detail page of the product can be viewed by Guest user also

Comment: I guess this will be the only solution. Thanks @ramamoorthy_villi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how sharing on facebook works:

When you share a link on Facebook, Twitter or any such service, the service crawls the shared page URL for fetching the metadata.

When you share an URL that is only accessible for authenticated users, there is no way for the crawlers to reach your URL. In Yii Framework, the request is redirected automatically to Login Page which is what the crawlers will see in your case.

Here is how we solved it in one of our previous application:

Added a different action for guest view for the particular page and redirect any non authenticated requests from main action to the guest view action. The guest view action will be similar to the main action except that the user will not be able do any actions here.

Example:

```
public function actionView(){
     if($isGues){
         //redirect to public function actionGuestview(){}
     }
     // Your Existing code to render the view file.
}
public function actionGuestView(){
     // Code to render the public view of the above action.
     // Make sure that the user cannot perform any actions here.
}
```